# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app

Tags: angularjs, codemirror

I have this error and i dont knew how to resolve them, if you can help me
My page html is follow

```
<html ng-app="app">
...    
<div ng-controller="codeCtrl">
        <textarea ui-codemirror ng-model="code">{{ code }}</textarea>
</div>
```

and my code js is follow:

```
        var myApp  = angular.module('app', ['ui']);

        myApp.value('ui.config', {
            codemirror: {
                lineNumbers: true,
                htmlMode: true,
                mode: "text/html",
                theme: "ambiance",
                indentWithTabs: false,
                readOnly: true,
                matchBrackets: true
            };                  
        });

        function codeCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.code= '<html style="color: green"> <head>    <title>HTML Example/title>  /head>    body> The indentation tries to be <em>somewhat &quot;do what  I mean&quot;/em>... but might not match your style.  </body> </html>';
        };
```

i take this error

```
 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
 [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name    or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as   the second argument.
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/nomod?p0=app
```

Comment: What is the `[ui]` module? Are you sure it's available?

Comment: Also, are you including those modules in the `index.html` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed to include js script in my html pages,
and i suggest to use ['ui.codemirror'] instead ['ui']

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the dependency `[ui]` is not included on your page and instantiated, 
also when you want to write controller you need to write like this:

```
function codeCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.code= '<html style="color: green"> <head>    <title>HTML Example/title>  /head>    body> The indentation tries to be <em>somewhat &quot;do what  I mean&quot;/em>... but might not match your style.  </body> </html>';
        };

myApp.controller('codeCtrl',codeCtrl);
```

Comment: its a race condition.